# photo editing app are these functions possible?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, image-processing

User would open the app and it would ask if User wants to use the camera or use a saved picture.
If user selects camera, it would link with the camera view so that they can immediately take a picture. 
Application would present the user with an outline of a human body so as to match up with a subject they wish to photograph.
[image]

Example – this would be clear except for the outline of the body and the user would be able to move the phone or have the subject move until they closely fit into the shape seen above. Once in position the subject would be photographed and the resulting photo WOULD NOT display the outline above. It is used for targeting and alignment only. Once photo is taken a set of clothing could be held up and the same outline above could be used to align the clothes within the shape and photographed thus allowing the two photos to be merged and the subject would see what the clothing would look like on them.
Application would then eliminate all of the image out side the body image. In more specific terms would isolate the subject from the subject’s surroundings. The result would be the subject alone in a blank field.
Now that subject is isolated application would allow for other images to be placed over subject image. (example: new clothes could be imaged in a similar manner as the subject and dragged on to the isolated image.

ok thanks for your answer.it really helps me alot..

now tell me if these functions are possible

Application will allow for adding isolated subject onto a background imaged stored on the iphone. (example: subject is photographed in San Francisco but background is replaced to make it appear subject is in New York City.
All functions described above should be available to be employed with stored images as well.
Image of subject should be able to be “morphed” to appear heavier or thinner.

Below are some additional desired features which are price sensitive – please provide an estimate based on adding some of these features. If a feature is listed below and it appears above please disregard.
Once photo is taken, app would ask user if they want to cut the head, replace the outfit or "try on". This would drive the subsequent actions.
If cut head is selected
User would circle the outline of the head and the app would cut out the image of the head and save to the side
User would then select another body from the picture, from a body template, or body from another saved/stored photo.
Once body is selected, user would touch the saved head and it will automatically fill on to the body.
If outfit is selected
User would touch key body parts such as the two shoulders, hands, waist, legs and feet from left to right. This would allow the app to know how best to superimpose the outfit.
User would then select an outfit from the many available templates
Once selected, user would hit a confirm type of button and this would put the new outfit on to the body.
The outfit should conform to the person's body in the photo. i.e. stretch side ways to make the person fatter, make thinner, shorter, longer, etc. 
If app could be aware of spatial alignment, that would be ideal. i.e. if someone is turned to the side, the replaced outfit would be a side view. 
Another feature should be is for the user to manually alter the photo with the new outfit to make the person look taller, shorter, skinnier, fatter, etc. 
App would also have option pose for frontal and rear view photo 
In the camera view when this option is selected, a standard body outline would show in the frame. The user would try and match as closely as possibly the subject to the body outline shown in the frame. Once closely matched, user would take the phone of the frontal and rear view of the subject. 
At clothing stores, the user can take a front and back photo of the clothes and have it superimposed to the "posed" photo of the body they took. 
User would open the app, and it would start as outlined in the first bullet point above
User would select the camera option
User would take the photo of the front and back of the clothing
Once photo taken, app would ask if they want to cut the head, replace the outfit, or try on..
User selects try on
App asks if it's a top, bottom, or both AND if user wants frontal/rear view of the clothing
User touches key points of the outfit as needed, ie. shoulders, wrist, waist, etc.
Once key points touched and confirmed, app automatically fits the clothing into the saved/posed photo
App would need to conform the clothing photo to the user's body shape and type.
The app should work for saved pictures as well. ie stores have pictures online and the user is able to copy and save the clothing photo from the store's website to their iphone and use this feature the same.

Comment: @Rahul Vyas: have you got solution if yes, post it it will help many.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The targetting part can be easily done in 3.1, you’ll simply set a view with a transparent body image as the custom camera view ([setCameraOverlayView](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView) docs). The body outline will only be visible in the view finder, not on the photograph. Once you have the image aligned, you can then separate the body image from the background using a PNG mask image with an alpha channel. This image would only show the parts that fall inside the body outline, and you can also have a decent feather on the border. I am just not sure about the quality of the resulting image, the aligning is bound to be pretty imprecise.

Comment: i have edited the question with more details.can you please guide me in this direction. how we could do morphing of image like make it heavy or thinner

Comment: I would love to vote up your answer more than once. As for the asker; change it to a different one.